# How to load Crystal Report before my main application open

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

I want to load crystal report files in my vb application before my main application open, because my crystal report slow in loading data when its first time to open it takes 10 to 15 secs. I see other softwares that also use crystal report with smooth loading of data.

How can I achieve this?

I use visual studio 2010 and Crystal Report for visual studio 2010.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new thread and load a dummy report with the start of the application

Comment: What do you mean load a dummy report? I need to load a blank report?

Comment: Yes, something that will load the dlls in memory.